# Storing React Routes in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am using `react-router` v4 to generate dynamic routes which are loaded from an asynchronous API. The data retrieved from the API is passed through a function which will create the React routes, something similar to:

```
import Home from "containers/home"
import FeaturePage from "containers/featurePage"

response.map((item) => {
  if (item.value.toLowerCase() === "home") {
    return {
      path: item.path,
      component: Home,
      exact: item.isExact
    }
  } else if (item.value.toLowerCase() === "featurePage") {
    return {
      path: item.path,
      component: FeaturePage,
      exact: item.isExact
    }
  } else {
      // ...etc
  }
});
```

Once the routes are loaded, they are added to the Redux store using an action-reducer as usual. This works well as the redux store supports functions.

However storing functions in the Redux store [doesn't seem to be the best way forward](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state). What would be a better implementation? I need to store the component which needs to be rendered, which is not serialisable.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the component name as strings? (Not sure why you wanna add them to the store though)

You can probably use them later like this:

```js
import Home from "containers/home"
import FeaturePage from "containers/featurePage"

// Assume the routes have been added to the redux store
const Routes = {
  Home,
  FeaturePage
};

response.map(({ component, path, exact }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      key={ path }
      exact={ exact }
      path={ path }
      component={ Routes[component] }
    />
  );
});
```

Comment: I managed to get this to work by storing the component name in the store and then passing the component name into a function which returns the Component. I need the component so that I could reference it when creating the `react-router` component.

```

import Home from "containers/home"

const getRouteComponent = name => {
  switch (name) {
    case "Home":
      return Home;
    default:
      return undefined;
  }
};

```

Comment: If you are able to update your example I can mark it as correct.

I create the `react-router` Route using:

{routes.map(route => {
          return (
            <Route
              key={route.path}
              exact
              path={route.path}
              component={getRouteComponent(route.component)}
            />
          );
        })}

Answer (score 0):

A React component is made up of the state of the component (made up of `state` and `props`) and some behavior (like functions and html markup) which is modified based on the state. Once you have created the component, the behavior of the component will not change; only the state of the component will change.

I would think saving the state of the component would be enough to recreate the component at a later time and you would not need to save the component in Redux; instead save the state of the component in Redux.

Regarding saving your Routes in Redux, the same applies; you should save the state of the Route rather than the route itself in your Redux store. You can have a function which could take this state object (containing the path, isExact, component name etc.) and convert it to a real component for you.

Hope this helps!